# django-forms how to get the previous values that the user has filled in respective fields

Tags: django, forms

I have a form in which i have fields like
FirstName :abc
LastName  :def
Dateofbirth:2011-10-14
.
.
.
.

during the registration user comes in and fill this form i have made an update link that allow the user to update his or her profile.

I want when i click on UpdateProfile Link it shows me the default values what user has filled previously according to his login password

as per the form the user should be able to see 
firstname:abc
lastname:def
.
.
.
.
and so on

How can i get the default value of a user according to his login and password

Answer (score 0):

Is this a plain form or a ModelForm?  This is very simple with a ModelForm.  You get the object representing the user which the ModelForm generates a form for and set the instance.  This example is a bit naive with the user auth and you may already have the user from a session id or whatever, but authentication isn't the point on this.

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username,password=password)
form=UserForm(instance=user)
```

Comment: @Daniel Roseman thanks for the catch on that .filter() to .get().  I'm always accidentally doing that.

Comment: I am using ModelForms .hey thanks it is working if i have models.but in my app i dont have models i am calling the database details from OpenErp connector.My database is OpenERP.What would i do in that situation.it says "type object 'Personal_info_updateForm' has no attribute 'objects'". i dont have models.Plwase help...

Comment: I'm not sure how you would properly interact with it using OpenErp connector.  I guess that means that Django is not doing any database interaction directly and is only acting as a front end?  I'm not having any luck finding any API docs, so unfortunately I can only guess.  If you can get the current object with the existing values you can still manually fill in initial form values when you initialize your form object with the "initial" parameter.

Comment: i have done that and it is showing me that values when i pass the values in a dictionary like this:---s = OEConnector()
        print s
        s.find('res.users', [('id','=',1)],[])dictUpdateData = {'name':'','first_name':'Nikhil','last_name':'Nikhil Verma','birthdate':'1988-10-14','mobile':'9582733156','email':'nikhilverma22@rediffmail.com','phone':'9582733156'
                      } f1 = Personal_info_updateForm(dictUpdateData)
return render_to_response('profile/personal_info.html',{'form':f1,'listCategories': listCategories})

Comment: Try this:  f1 = Personal_info_updateForm(initial=dictUpdateData)

Answer (score 0):

Password(render_value=True),you can try it